# ColdFusion 10 Update Killed My Admin

Tags: iis, coldfusion

So, I used the updater in CF Admin to apply the latest patch (14) to CF10.  Afterwards, I rebuilt my web server connections.  This is a process I've done dozens of times.  However, this time around I've lost the ability to get to my CF Administrator....but all my sites are running just fine!  I just can't access the Administrator!  I've removed/recreated the connectors and restarted IIS/CF 3 times.  Same thing.

Everything about this server was running fine up to now.    It is Win 2008/IIS7

I'm getting the dreaded IIS HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error:

Module  IsapiModule
Notification    ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler ISAPI-dll
Error Code  0x00000000
Requested URL   http://thewebsiteimtalkingabout.com:80/jakarta/isapi_redirect.dll
Physical Path   D:\My_Web_Sites\config\wsconfig\2\isapi_redirect.dll
Logon Method    Anonymous
Logon User  Anonymous

I have 2 other identical servers that I have yet to update so they continue to run fine.  I've been referencing each of them to see if there were some permissions or other oddball changes.  Can't find anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: Paul, Can you reach out to cfinstal<AT>adobe<DOT>com

Comment: Do you still have a /CFIDE virtual directory setup in your IIS site?

Comment: Yes, every site's 'CFIDE' directory is a virtual one pointing to the server's actual CFIDE.  I've checked permissions and they appear OK but can't help but think the problem lies there.  Still looking....

Comment: Can you specify your machine bitness and ColdFusion bitness. Also check if there is any error in EventViewer. Provide the error code and data from this error. Also enable FrebLogs in IIS, hit the cfm, xml will be generated giving complete error, provide that xml.